# Understanding comb filter implementation of Freeverb

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

I try to understand the implementation of the low-pass comb filter of the Freeverb reverberation algorithm:

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Lowpass_Feedback_Comb_Filter.html

The original implementation is as follows:

```
inline float comb::process(float input)
{
    float output;
    output = buffer[bufidx];
    filterstore = (output*damp2) + (filterstore*damp1);
    buffer[bufidx] = input + (filterstore*feedback);
    if(++bufidx>=bufsize) bufidx = 0;
    return output;
}
```

I drew the closed loop of this algorithm:

[image]

1. Am I interpreting the algorithm correct?
2. What is the lower feedback branch exactly doing here?

Can someone help me understanding this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

filterstore is the feedback of a filter. Looks like lower feedback branch is a basic low-pass filter.
So this is a simple delay with feedback, having a low-pass filter in the feedback path.